# jQuery select elements with incrementing ID's

Tags: jquery

I would like to select list items based on their incrementing ID's but I am having a bit of trouble. Thoughts?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var listCount = 1;

    $('#listitem-' + listCount + ' a').hover(function() {
            $('#anotheritem-' + listCount).show();
            return false;
    });

    listCount++;
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="cap">
   <li id="listitem-1"><a href="#">content 1</a></li>
   <li id="listitem-2"><a href="#">content 2</a></li>
   <li id="listitem-3"><a href="#">content 3</a></li>
   <li id="listitem-4"><a href="#">content 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div style="display:none;" id="anotheritem-1">hello 1</div>
<div style="display:none;" id="anotheritem-3">hello 3</div>
<div style="display:none;" id="anotheritem-3">hello 3</div>
<div style="display:none;" id="anotheritem-4">hello 4</div>
```

UPDATED Question. I'm trying to achieve the following revision of the answer:

```
$('.listitem_to_hover').hover(function () { 
    var senderID = sender.id.replace('listitem-', '');
     $('#anotheritem-' + senderID).show();
}, function () { 
    var senderID = sender.id.replace('listitem-', '');
     $('#anotheritem-' + senderID).hide();
});
```

Comment: What kind of trouble? Can you post your html. Is your code in a for or while loop? You wouldn't be able to just use a selector instead?

Comment: it's simply selecting the first list item. Something wrong with my loop i assume.

Comment: Can you please post your loop, and anything else related to this.

Comment: This is a mystery the way you present it. Please provide more portion of your script and html

Comment: sorry here is html <ul id="cap">
 <li id="listitem-1"><a href="#">content 1</a></li>
 <li id="listitem-2"><a href="#">content 2</a></li>
 <li id="listitem-3"><a href="#">content 3</a></li>
 <li id="listitem-4"><a href="#">content 4</a></li></ul>

Comment: Take of the markup off the comment section. Re Edit your question with complete, clean related script and markup

Comment: sry -- having trouble posting here. First time. That is the full script. I am simply trying to select items based on ID

Comment: Why do you use a loop anyway? You could just give the ul an id or class and select the lis from there like $('ul#list li').hover(...);

Comment: I eventually need to call other elements associate with that ID. For instance #listitem-1 will show(); #hiddenimage-1

Comment: updated once again to give a bit more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are looping through (or trying to loop through) to assign your hover function, why not use a class selector instead:

```
//changing # to . makes jquery select ALL of the elements with that class assigned.

$('.listitem_to_hover').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('current');
return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="cap">
   <li id="listitem-1" class="listitem_to_hover"><a href="#">content 1</a></li>
   <li id="listitem-2" class="listitem_to_hover"><a href="#">content 2</a></li>
   <li id="listitem-3" class="listitem_to_hover"><a href="#">content 3</a></li>
   <li id="listitem-4" class="listitem_to_hover"><a href="#">content 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

*ps: even after you edit your document.ready... you don't have a loop?*

**Okay, based on what you have shown, this should get you want you want: **

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.listitem_to_hover').hover(function () { showItem(this); }, function () { hideItem(this); })
        });

        function showItem(sender) {
        var senderID = sender.id.replace('listitem-', '');
        $('#anotheritem-' + senderID).fadeIn();// .removeClass('hidden');
    }

    function hideItem(sender) {
        var senderID = sender.id.replace('listitem-', '');
        $('#anotheritem-' + senderID).fadeOut(); //.addClass('hidden');
    }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hidden
        {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <ul id="cap">
            <li id="listitem-1" class="listitem_to_hover"><a href="#">content 1</a></li>
            <li id="listitem-2" class="listitem_to_hover"><a href="#">content 2</a></li>
            <li id="listitem-3" class="listitem_to_hover"><a href="#">content 3</a></li>
            <li id="listitem-4" class="listitem_to_hover"><a href="#">content 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="hidden" id="anotheritem-1">
            hello 1</div>
        <div class="hidden" id="anotheritem-2">
            hello 2</div>
        <div class="hidden" id="anotheritem-3">
            hello 3</div>
        <div class="hidden" id="anotheritem-4">
            hello 4</div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because I will eventually revise the code to select another ID. For instance #listitem-1 will show(); #hiddenimage-1

Comment: Ok, that should not matter. If what you are saying is you want to 'change the code so that when you hover over a list item a hidden image is shown by id' then you can assign the hover function by class and still identify the id of the source (the particular li) in the handler, where you can then show the corresponding image.

Comment: Yes, but the corresponding image will not be located within the LI. I've updated my original post to give a bit more detail

Comment: @klav, I have updated the answer.. you see that you don't need for the external target to be inside the same LI to get your desired result.

Comment: @Cos Callis: Ahh, I see what's going on. Exactly what I needed! Thanks a million!

Comment: @Cos Callis: I'm now working to include fadeIn(), fadeOut() with no luck. I've updated my original question with the revisied code. Any thoughts?

Comment: @klav, substitute fadeIn/Out for add/removeclass (I have edited the sample above)

Comment: @Cos Callis: Thanks for getting back to me on this! Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I had tried this solution originally but nothing is firing.

Comment: @klav it works perfectly for me. you might try adding "slow" to the command like `fadeIn('slow')` and see if that makes it more obvious. Other than that look to the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: @Cos Callis: It looks like the culprit was the class (.hidden) being declared twice. I forgot it was located in another imported sheet. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all your code it's hard to be sure, but could you not give all your list items the same class - eg `<li class="foo">`

Then

```
$(".foo a").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('current');
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I just updated my original entry.

Comment: Based on this - the code about should work if you add class="foo" to each li element

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a the parent ul as a selector

```
$('#cap li a').hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('current');       
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding a class to every list item i'd just select them over the ul.

```
$('#cap li a').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('current');
    return false;
});
```